help me please to prove the following theorem in topology about compact spaces with this way
If $X$ is Hausdorff, $A \subseteq X$ compact, and $x \in A$, then there exist $U, V \subseteq X$ open and disjoint such that $x \in U$ and $A \subseteq V$. In particular, $A$ is closed.
Proof: Let $x \in A$. Then for each $y \in A$ there are regions $U_y$ and $V_y$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such so that $U_y \cap V_y = \emptyset$. The family $\{ V_y | y \in A \}$, is an open covering of $A$, so there exist $y_1, \dots, y_n \in A$.

For  some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

What does $x < A$ mean? And please use mathjax. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

You are basically trying to show that a Hausdorff space is "regular" with respect to points disjoint from compact sets. (In a regular space, there exist disjoint open sets separating a point and any closed set missing that point.)
Let $X$ be Hausdorff, and $x \in X$. Let $A \subseteq X$ be a compact set that misses $x$. We will find a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an open set $V$ containing $A$ such that $U, V$ are disjoint.
Arbitrarily choose, for each point $y \in A$, disjoint neighborhoods $U_y$ of $x$ and $V_y$ of $y$; define $\mathcal{V} = \{V_y | y \in A\}$. Note that $\mathcal{V}$ is an open cover of $A$. Since $A$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover with $V_{y_1} \cup \dots \cup V_{y_N} = V \supseteq A$. Then, let $U = U_{y_1} \cap \dots \cap U_{y_N} \ni x$. It is easy to see that $U$ and $V$, being finite intersections and unions of open sets, are open. It is just as easy to check that they are disjoint, since $U_{y_i}$ misses $V_{y_i}$ for each $1 \le i \le N$, and any $z \in U$ is contained in all $U_{y_i}$.
